# How to pass on objects as parameter to function in powerbuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

I am using powerbuilder 9 .0.1 Build 7171 I want to write a generalised 
function to handle object properties like font name. I want to change font
of the object buttons, list box idea is I will just pass on
window name or window handle and function will get the control list and if
control.type is listbox or button or picture button it will change its font.

I don't want to write windows function for every window is there any
way where I can just manipulate properties of windows

FOR n = 1 to UpperBound(Control[])
  IF Control[n].TypeOf() = CommandButton! OR Control[n].TypeOf() = PictureButton!THEN 
   set_button_name(this.Control[n])
  End if
NEXT

In this case I have to hardcode this code in open event of every window
to call this by using function()

Answer (score 5):

So, you've really got two issues:

1. How to get the list of controls (you don't ask, but based on the code snippet, you do)
2. How to start with a WindowObject and change an attribute that is associated with a descendant

**List of Controls**

You've got an implicit reference to the window's Control array, which is a good first step, but may neglect embedded Control arrays in objects like tabs and userobjects. A function like the following (*warning: untested, for illustration only*) will recurse through all your controls, and handle cases like tabs within tabs.

```
function of_getcontrols (windowobject awo_input[], ref windowobject awo_output[]) returns integer

long ll_Input, ll_InputCount, ll_OutputCount, ll_Sub, ll_SubCount
window lw_Control
userobject luo_UserObject
tab ltb_Tab
windowobject lwo_Empty[], lwo_Sub[]

awo_Output = lwo_Empty

ll_InputCount = UpperBound (awo_Input)
FOR ll_Input = 1 TO ll_InputCount
    ll_OutputCount ++
    awo_Output[ll_OutputCount] = awo_Input[ll_Input]

    // look for nested control arrays
    CHOOSE CASE awo_Input[ll_Input].TypeOf()
        CASE UserObject!
            luo_UserObject = awo_Input[ll_Input]
            ll_SubCount = of_GetControls (luo_UserObject.Control, lwo_Sub)
            FOR ll_Sub = 1 TO ll_SubCount
                ll_OutputCount ++
                awo_Output[ll_OutputCount] = lwo_Sub[ll_Sub]
            NEXT

        CASE Tab!
            ltb_Tab = awo_Input[ll_Input]
            ll_SubCount = of_GetControls (ltb_Tab.Control, lwo_Sub)
            FOR ll_Sub = 1 TO ll_SubCount
                ll_OutputCount ++
                awo_Output[ll_OutputCount] = lwo_Sub[ll_Sub]
            NEXT
    END CHOOSE
NEXT

RETURN ll_OutputCount
```

**Casting**

The next issue is how to access or manipulate an attribute of an object where the compiler doesn't recognize ownership of that attribute to that object's type. The solution is casting to a type where the compiler will recognize the attribute association. You saw casting in the sample above:

```
userobject luo_UserObject
...
luo_UserObject = awo_Input[ll_Input]
...luo_UserObject.Control...
```

The compiler wouldn't have recognized the association between the WindowObject and the Control array I was trying to reference, so I cast the WindowObject to a UserObject by assigning the WindowObject to a variable of type UserObject. After that, I can reference the Control array via that variable.

You'll be doing something similar to mine, probably inside a loop doing a CHOOSE CASE TypeOf(), then inside each CASE casting to a specific variable matching the type and manipulating the attribute there.

I'm guessing you were hoping there was a one-line assignment option, but there's not in PowerScript. (If it was a function you were calling on each, you could use the DYNAMIC keyword calling the function on the WindowObject, but it would be your responsibility to ensure that function was there before you called it.) I *believe* there's a way to directly do this with PBNI, but I can't help you with that, and I strongly suspect it's far more effort than it's worth.

Good luck,

Terry.

Comment: Pash, Terry has answered it quite eloquently.  Drilling through the object hierarchy is somewhat analogous to making changes to the DOM in a web page, but without a fancy framework like JQuery to make the job easier.